# execute after x seconds - use async task or timer ticks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

currently I'm using a timer to poll every x seconds. I've seen that I could also use asyncronous tasks to execute a function after x seconds.

So I've created an example for reproduction. This is how I would use a polling timer

```
class UseTimer
{
    public UseTimer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");

        Timer myTimer = new Timer(2000);
        myTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
            myTimer.Enabled = false;
        };

        myTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The code first logs *Foo*, then waits 2 seconds for the first timer tick and then logs *Bar*. I tried to reproduce it by using async/await

```
class UseAsync
{
    public UseAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        Do().Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async Task Do()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

The behaviour seems to be the same when I test it with this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // UseAsync a = new UseAsync();
        UseTimer t = new UseTimer();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I could or even should switch to async because it's easier to maintain and takes out complexity but remains the same way under the hood.

Comment: `Task.Delay` uses a timer to complete a task after an interval, so in the end it's all timers. There are at least [2 different multi-threaded timer classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) though and both run their callbacks/events on a threadpool thread. They don't need `async await`. Your code on the other hand doesn't really run asynchronously, it just calls `Do()` once and then blocks

Comment: For your question using async at all or not, it depends on what you do in your thread process. As more it is - as more lines of code, as more useful it might be, for just Console output it's probably not worth it.Especially any kind of user interaction should not be done in backgrond threads.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Actually there is only one type of timer. System.Timers.Timer is implemented by using a System.Threading.Timer. (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/src/System/Timers/Timer.cs/). The Timers.Timer has the nicer API and is us easier to understand so you should stick to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Every** x seconds" is different from "**after** x seconds".

If you need to run something (repeatedly) *every* x seconds, use a `Timer`.

If you need to run something (only once) *after* x seconds, use `Task.Delay`.

As noted in the comments, `Task.Delay` [uses a `System.Threading.Timer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5896) anyway, it's just easier to use for a single wait, and keeps your code clean.

Also, it's not wise to use asynchronous methods in a class constructor. Class constructors cannot be `async`, and thus you end up blocking the thread (as you did when using `Wait()`), or "fire and forget". If you need to do anything asynchronous while creating a new object, you can use a "factory method": a static method that creates the object for you. Then you make the constructor `private` to force everyone to use the factory method:

```cs
class UseAsync
{
    private UseAsync() {}

    public static async Task<UseAsync> CreateUseAsync()
    {
        var myC = new UseAsync();
        await myC.Do();
        return myC;
    }

    private async Task Do()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance like this:

```cs
var a = await UseAsync.CreateUseAsync();
```

I've done this when I need to retrieve data from somewhere before an object is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

The console.readline should be outside useAsync method, if not the task Do will not be executed

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UseAsync.UseAsyn();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

static class UseAsync
{
    public static async Task UseAsyn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        await Do();
    }

    private static async Task Do()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```